# Get data from a web table with table tag

Tags: html, vba, web, tags, html-table

I have this code in HTML:

```
<table cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "0" width = "100%" border="0">
<td class="TOlinha2"><span id="Co">140200586125</span>
```

I already have a VBA function that accesses a web site, logs in and goes to the right page. Now I'm trying to take the `td` tags inside a table in HTML. The value I want is `140200586125`, but I want a lot of `td` tags, so I intend to use a for loop to get those `td`s and put them in a worksheet.

I have tried both:

```
.document.getElementByClass()
```

and:

```
.document.getElementyById()
```

but neither worked.

Appreciate the help. I'm from Brazil, so sorry about any English mistakes.

Comment: Can you provide the URL so we can test our solutions?

Comment: sorry, this is a private web site from my work, now I'm at University, the only thing a can do is tomorrou post a bigger part of the code if it helps.

Comment: If you tried `.document.getElementById` (I'm presuming the extra y in getElementy<- is a typo), did you also try `.document.getElementById("Co").InnerText`? Its tough to help when we can't see your actual code and the page you are trying to scrape.

Comment: I haven't tried, But I will. If I don't get a answer before tomorrow I will post all the code, I'm sorry, but right now I don't have it. But thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough HTML to determine if the `TOlinha2` is a consistent class name for all the tds within the table of interest; and is limited only to this table. If it is then you can indeed use `.querySelectorAll`

You could use the [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors):

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll(".TOlinha2")
```

Where [`"."`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) stands for className.

You **cannot** iterate over the returned NodeList with a `For Each Loop`. See my question [Excel crashes when attempting to inspect DispStaticNodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021133/excel-crashes-when-attempting-to-inspect-dispstaticnodelist). Excel will crash and you will lose any unsaved data.

You have to loop the length of the nodeList e.g.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To Len(nodeList) -1
    Debug.Print nodeList(i).innerText    
Next i
```

Sometimes you need different syntax which is:

```
Debug.Print nodeList.Item(i).innerText
```

You can seek to further narrow this CSS selector down with more qualifying elements such as, the element must be within tbody i.e. a `table`, and preceeded by a `tr` (table row) and have classname `.TOLinha2`

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr .TOlinha2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you need to retrieve multiple `<td>` tags, it would make more sense to retrieve the entire collection rather than using `getElementById()` to get them one-at-a-time.

Based on your HTML above, this would match all `<span>` nodes within a `<td>` with a `class='TOlinha2'`:

```
Dim node, nodeList
Set nodeList = ie.document.querySelectorAll("td.TOlinha2 > span")

For Each node In nodeList
    MsgBox node.innerText     ' This should return the text within the <span>
Next
```