# Extract innerText from HTML div tags un a local file

Tags: html, excel, vba

I was able to extract table from a local HTML file using this code below, but I have no idea how to modify it to extract innertext from nested div tags in the sample HTML code below.

```
Sub HTML_Table_To_Excel() 

Dim htm As Object 
Dim Tr As Object 
Dim Td As Object 
Dim Tab1 As Object
Dim file as String
'Replace the file path with your own 
file = "c:\your_File.html"

'Determine the next file number available for use by the FileOpen function
TextFile = FreeFile

'Open the text file
 Open file For Input As TextFile

 'Create HTMLFile Object 
 Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile") 
 HTML_Content.body.innerHtml = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)

 Column_Num_To_Start = 1 
 iRow = 2 
 iCol = Column_Num_To_Start 
 iTable = 0 

'Loop Through Each Table and Download it to Excel in Proper Format 
For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table") 
With HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("table")(iTable) 
    For Each Tr In .Rows 
    For Each Td In Tr.Cells 
        Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iCol).Select 
        Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, iCol) = Td.innerText 
        iCol = iCol + 1 
        Next Td 
        iCol = Column_Num_To_Start 
        iRow = iRow + 1 
    Next Tr 
End With 

iTable = iTable + 1 
iCol = Column_Num_To_Start 
iRow = iRow + 1 
Next Tab1 

MsgBox "Process Completed" 
End Sub
```

And here is the HTML code without tables

[image]

I want to copy all the report-row-label classes into the Sheet

Comment: please don't post pictures of code. Use the snippet tool via [edit] to share html.

Comment: Where in the sheet do you want the values to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use late-bound `HTMLFile`. It's like going for a run in clogs. It uses IE version below 9, which doesn't support `.getElementsByClassName` method or `querySelector/querySelectorAll`.

The early bound `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` is accessible via the `Microsoft HTML Object Library`; a standard shipped library that Microsoft paid a lot of money in an anti-trust settlement to ensure is present in all installs. The only scenario I can think of where this would be a problem is with a "cut-off their nose to spite their face" IT dept refusing to install for a rights-restricted user on a work machine. You aren't going to have version issues either.

Then you can use the `class`attribute to target the nodes of interest with either of the methods I mentioned above. A [likely bug in the provision of an enumeration method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50022047/6241235) means that you can't `For Each` over the `DispStaticNodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` (unlike with the collection returned by `getElementsByClassName`); you can, however, use a `For Loop` to run the `.Length` of the nodeList.

Alter the below to write out where you want in sheet:

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long

Set nodeList = HTML_Content.querySelectorAll(".report-row-label") 'or use HTML_Content.getElementsByClassName("report-row-label") method and value

For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
    Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 1) = nodeList.Item(i).innertext
Next
```

Of course, the above is with adding reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library` via VBE>Tools>References and then declaring and instantiating a `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` instance.

```
Dim HTML_Content As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set HTML_Content = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
```

Then populating the variable's `.body.innerHTML` with your file content as before.

With `getElementsByClassName` you should be able to do something like as follows:

```
Dim nodeList As Object, node As Object, i As Long 'change these to use explicit types here for the element and element collection types

Set nodeList = HTML_Content.getElementsByClassName("report-row-label")

For Each node In nodeList
    Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 1) = node.innerText
    i = i + 1
Next
```