# Loop through elements in list LI tag

Tags: excel, vba, css-selectors

I am trying to learn about scraping and I got a html part that I need to loop through the elements of a list and get the information from each header. There are 7 elements in the html

```html
<ul class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical"><li><span class="a-list-item"><span class="a-text-bold">Geschäftsname:</span>Anker Technology (UK) Ltd</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item"><span class="a-text-bold">Geschäftsart:</span>Ltd.</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item"><span class="a-text-bold">Handelsregisternummer:</span>8766135</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item"><span class="a-text-bold">UStID:</span>DE295307777</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item"><span class="a-text-bold">Telefonnummer:</span>+49 69 9579 7960</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item"><span class="a-text-bold">Kundendienstadresse:</span><ul class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical"><li><span class="a-list-item">610 Nathan Road, Hollywood Commercial Center</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item">Room 1318-19</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item">Hong Kong</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item">Hong Kong</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item">999077</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item">HK</span></li></ul></span></li><li><span class="a-list-item"><span class="a-text-bold">Geschäftsadresse:</span><ul class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical"><li><span class="a-list-item">Suite B, Fairgate House, 205 Kings Road, Tyseley,</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item">Birmingham</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item">B11 2AA</span></li><li><span class="a-list-item">GB</span></li></ul></span></li></ul>
```

I tried this

```
post = mhtml.querySelectorAll(".a-list-item .a-text-bold")
```

and this doesn't give me an error but how can loop through the object elements?

I tried such lines

```
            For Each e In post
            Debug.Print e.innerText
        Next e
```

but throws error

When I debug the innerhtml of the post

```
Debug.Print post.innerHTML
```

I got only this in the immidate window "Gesch?ftsname:" although in the html page when I inspect the css selector `.a-list-item .a-text-bold` O got 7 results.

Comment: have you populated a variable that you can `for each` through?

Comment: Yes I tried using For Each statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

querySelectorAll returns a nodeList which due to a likely [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021133/excel-crashes-when-attempting-to-inspect-dispstaticnodelist) cannot be For Each'd over. Instead, you need to traverse using the .Length property

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To post.Length -1
   Debug.Print post.item(i).innerText
Next
```

You need to SET the object reference and test the nodeType of the NextSiblings if you wish to retrieve the list of headers and associated values:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetInfo()
    Dim http As msxml2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, post As Object

    Set http = New msxml2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.amazon.de/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=&isAmazonFulfilled=1&isCBA=&marketplaceID=A1PA6795UKMFR9&orderID=&seller=A2PGPJL0BBLHLX&tab=&vasStoreID=", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set post = html.querySelectorAll(".a-list-item .a-text-bold")

    Dim i As Long, sibling As Object, val As Variant

    For i = 0 To post.Length - 1
        Set sibling = post.item(i).NextSibling

        Debug.Print post.item(i).innerText, " = "

        Select Case sibling.NodeType
        Case 3
            val = sibling.NodeValue
        Case 1
            val = sibling.innerText
        End Select

        Debug.Print val
    Next

    Stop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got an error Object doesn't support this property or method at the line `For i = 0 To post.Length -1`

Comment: Did you declare post As Object? Also what does debug.print typename(post) give you?

Comment: I got typename `HTMLSpanElement`. When I declared post as object I got error at my line of setting post. It seems as object in Nothing.

Comment: What's the url? querySelectorAll should not return an HTMLSpanElement. And how are you retrieving the html? xhr or browser?

Comment: This is the url [LINK](https://www.amazon.de/gp/help/seller/at-a-glance.html/ref=dp_merchant_link?ie=UTF8&seller=A2PGPJL0BBLHLX&isAmazonFulfilled=1)

Comment: How are you retrieving content? Can you add more of your code please?

Comment: You are also missing the SET keyword for the object reference

Comment: You are the MAN. Yes that is the point. But now I got the headers of the elements. How can I get the information related to it?Will I use nextsiblking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210631/discussion-between-yasserkhalil-and-qharr).